# Find file offset of a symbol with nm

Tags: macos, reverse-engineering, nm

I'm trying to patch a program with scripts. So I'll need the file offset of a symbol,

But nm only prints the address in memory, how can I find its file offset?

```
%> nm a | grep checkUpdate
000000010010f8ff t -[UIManager checkUpdate]
```

I'm running nm on Mac

Comment: How is that the address in memory?  The file isn't loaded.

Comment: @trojanfoe because it's bigger than file size

Comment: You'll need to know something about how the file is mapped into memory.  The start of the text area is something like `100000000` so if you can figure out where the text area starts in the file, the symbol is likely at offset `10f8ff` from there.  What you are doing is very advanced, so I would expect you to already know this...

Answer (score 0):

Let us say we want to find the offset of `var2`:

```
int var1 = 1;
int var2 = 2;

int main(){}
```

After building, `nm` gives:

```
nm -a a.out | grep var
0000000100001000 D _var1
0000000100001004 D _var2
```

With `gobjdump` (`port install binutils`) we can read the program header:

```
gobjdump -x a.out

a.out:     file format mach-o-x86-64
a.out
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000012:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000100000f90

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000000b  0000000100000f90  0000000100000f90  00000f90  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
  1 __TEXT.__unwind_info 00000048  0000000100000f9c  0000000100000f9c  00000f9c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .eh_frame     00000018  0000000100000fe8  0000000100000fe8  00000fe8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .data         00000008  0000000100001000  0000000100001000  00001000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000100000000 g       0f SECT   01 0010 [.text] __mh_execute_header
0000000100000f90 g       0f SECT   01 0000 [.text] _main
0000000100001000 g       0f SECT   04 0000 [.data] _var1
0000000100001004 g       0f SECT   04 0000 [.data] _var2
0000000000000000 g       01 UND    00 0100 dyld_stub_binder
```

Thus the address of `var2` returned by `nm` is in section `.data`, which is loaded at virtual memory address `100001000` and has file offset `1000`. You can get the file offset of `var2`as `100001004 - 100001000 + 1000 = 1004`.

This can be verified with a hex editor:

```
256 0000ff0: 017a 5200 0178 1001 100c 0708 9001 0000  .zR..x..........
257 0001000: 0100 0000 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
258 0001010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```